# Updating user address table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to update user address. It's adding record to the database successfully, but when it comes to displaying current version of address on the website, I have to hit re-submit first.

> To view this page, information previously sent by Firefox needs to be resubmitted. When you resubmit your data, each action made on the form (such as a search or online order) will be repeated.

Php code in folder profileUpdate.php

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
        $last_name  = $_POST["last_name"];
        $street     = $_POST["street"];
        $city       = $_POST["city"];
        $country    = $_POST["country"];
        $zip        = $_POST["zip"];
        $phone_no   = $_POST["phone_no"];

    if (empty($first_name) || empty($last_name) || empty($street) || empty($city) || empty($country) || empty($zip) || empty($phone_no) ) {
        $response->success = false;
        $response->message = 'All fields must be filled.';
    } else {

            $sql_address_update = "UPDATE address AS a\n"
                . "INNER JOIN customer AS c ON a.customer_ID = c.customer_ID\n"
                . "SET a.`first_name` = ?, a.`last_name` = ?, a.`street` = ?, a.`city` = ?, a.`country` = ?, a.`zip` = ?, a.`phone_no` = ?\n"
                . "WHERE (c.`email` = '". $email . "')";
            try {

                //Create customer
                $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sql_address_update);
                $preparedStatement->bind_param('sssssii', $first_name, $last_name, $street, $city, $country, $zip, $phone_no);
                $preparedStatement->execute();


                $response->success = true;
                $response->message = 'Account created.';


                // $api=new SMSApi('Group07','129DFCF1651D3E75');
                // $reply=$api->SendEmailv2($email,"Verification","Hi. Follow this link to verify your account: https://139.59.131.217/verify.php?email=".$email."&ver=".$verificationString);
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $response->success = false;
                $errorCode         = $e->getCode();
                if ($errorCode == 23000) //username and email columns are UNIQUE, this error code means violation of this rule (duplicate data)
                    {
                    $response->message = 'Duplicate username or email.';
                } else {
                    $response->message = "Error.";
                }
            }
        }
    }

$connection = null;
```

profile.php file

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-sm-10 mb-xs-30">
   <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ while($row = $result_address->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
   <h3> Address <a style="font-size:12px" id="edit">EDIT</a></h3>
   <p id="p">Name: <?php echo $row['first_name']. " " .$row['last_name'];?><br/>
      Street: <?php echo $row['street'];?><br/>
      City: <?php echo $row['city'];?><br/>
      Country: <?php echo $row['country'];?><br/>
      Zip code: <?php echo $row['zip'];?><br/>
      Phone: <?php echo $row['phone_no'];?>
   </p>
   <?php }}?>
   <!-- EDIT FORM -->
   <form method="post" action='#' id="form" role="form" onsubmit="" class="form">
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <!-- First Name -->
         <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="First name" maxlength="20" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <!-- Last Name -->
         <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="Surname" maxlength="100" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <!-- Street -->
         <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="Street" maxlength="100" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <!-- City -->
         <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="City" maxlength="100" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <select class="input-md form-control" type="text" id="country" name="country" required />
            <option disabled selected>Select country..</option>
            <option value="dk">Denmark</option>
            <option value="cz">Czech Republic</option>
            <option value="pl">Poland</option>
            <option value="hu">Hungary</option>
            <option value="sk">Slovakia</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <!-- Zipcode -->
         <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="Zip code"required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <!-- Phonenumber -->
         <input type="text" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max10" class="input-md form-control" placeholder="Phone number" required />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
         <button class="btn btn-mod btn-small update" type="submit" name="submit" value="update" id="updateBtn">Upadate information</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

```js
        $('#edit').on('click',function() 
         {
         $('#p, #form').toggle();
         }
         );

         $( "#updateBtn" ).click(function() {
         $( "#p" ).toggle( "slow");
         $( "#form" ).hide();
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can you please give me advice how to make it without re-submitting the form & showing result right away?

I tried to use Ajax as well but I have probabl some flaw in the code

```js
 $(function() {
  $("#update").click(function() {
  vvar first_name = $("#first_name").val();
  var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
  var street = $("#street").val();
  var city = $("#city").val();
  var coutnry = $("#country").val();
  var zip = $("#zip").val();
  var phone_no = $("#phone_no").val();
  var dataString = 'first_name='+ first_name + '&last_name=' + last_name + '&street=' + street + '&city=' + city + '&coutnry=' + country + '&zip=' + zip; + '&phone_no=' + phone_no;

if(first_name=='' || last_name=='' || city=='' || country=='' || zip=='' || phone_no=='')
{
  //
}
else
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "profileUpdate.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
     //
    }
  });
}
return false;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: redirect user after your form submit action using `header('location:....')`, so it won't ask for re-submit the data

Comment: @NishantSolanki I tried this before action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" but it didn't really worked, isn't it the same thing?

Comment: is your form getting submitted using js+ajax? if yes then please provide your full JS code where form submit js is written

Comment: @NishantSolanki I added code snippet of AJAX I was trying to use, but there is probably some flaw

Comment: So as per my understanding, your form is getting posted via ajax call, the page you have currently loaded shows the old address of the user, and if you reload the page the new address shows but the form is re-submitted..

Comment: in your ajax `success: function(){}` try adding this line `window.location = window.location.href;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the results right away you need to take a different approach to this. PHP can't render output at run-time. Ajax can however. This is quite fluffy but I suggest you read up on ajax post/get calls.

This video shows the basics of retrieving data & showing it "live"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvagmRhTG4w&index=4&list=PLQj6bHfDUS-b5EXUbHVQ21N_2Vli39w0k

God dag :)

Comment: Or else you could simply do


`header('location:'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].');`

Comment: I have tried  ` header('location:'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'); ` before and it was really working.

Comment: Wans't. I am sorry that was a typo

Comment: try to echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] and check if it returns the same URL as the one you're currently on. Also, where in your code did you place the header location snippet - and did you remember that you cannot echo header location?